# SML - Finding an element in the list and changing it's value

Tags: sml

I'm new to SML. I'm writing a function which accepts 2 int and a list of tuples as input:

```
fun moveBoxL(Xw,Yw,boxes:(int * int)list) =
```

The length of my list(boxes) can change. I want to find a tuple in the list whose elements are equal to Xw,Yw. For example I want a tuple like box1 whose elements are like this: box1=(Xw,Yw) and if there was such a tuple, I want to change it's value => box1(Xw-1,Yw-1) .
Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun moveBox (x, y, boxes) = List.map (fn p => if p = (x,y) then (x-1,y-1) else p) boxes
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to check multiple condition using List.map and change 2 of tuples? For example to find a tuple like box1 whose value is box1=(Xw,Yw) and a tuple like box2=(Xw,Yw-1) and change their value for example to => box1=(Xw+1,Yw-1) & box2=(Xw-1,Yw-1) simultaneously?

Comment: Sure, just add an `else if` condition.

Comment: But I want both of them occur at the same time. I mean: if List.exists (fn s => s = (X,Y)) boxes andalso List.exists (fn p => p = (X,Y)) boxes then .... (then for example change and return s=(X-1,Y-1) andalso p=(X-2,Y-2) I wanted to know how can I write this condition using List.map to change their value at the same time?